# Who owns the rights to Doctor Who – The Ultimate Adventure and is the script available?

Tags: doctor-who, theater-play

Is the *Doctor Who* stage play available for production?

Comment: I’m not too familiar with Doctor Who but it appears as though your title and body questions don’t match, could you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: You mean right now? Ever? I don't know either way, but maybe you should clarify.

Answer (score 3):

The most recent rights-*users* were Big Finish Audio. They produced an [audio-drama](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ultimate_Adventure_(audio_story)) version of the play in 2008 which credited BBC Worldwide as the rights-holders. Similarly, a 1989 [audio-play](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgDCtdyiAZs) version produced for the BBC also credits the BBC as the *mark-holders* and **[BBC Worldwide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_Worldwide) as the *rights-holders*.** I see no good reason why this shouldn't continue to be the case.

[image]

The original writer (Terrance Dicks) & producer Mark Furness, who apparently paid the princely sum of £500,000 for the rights to use the Doctor Who, Daleks and Cybermen characters (as well as various trademarks such as the Tardis) may also have some say over whether and when their creation can be used.

> **Furness negotiated rights from the BBC, and found the costly £500,000
> budget.** The dazzling on-stage special effects, involving both lasers
> and computer graphics, came from Foys of Las Vegas who, among their
> many stage productions, had produced the simulated space walks for
> NASA. Rehearsals began 27 February 1989 for a Thursday, 23 March
> opening date in Wimbledon Theatre.
>
> <sub><sup>Doctor Who - The Ultimate Adventure By Mark Olsen</sup></sub>

---

There is currently no *legal* version of the script available to purchase but there is a transcript of the audio-play available online [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/Extras/UltimatePertwee.html)